# MySQL select Current_timestamp between

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I have a list of users in MySQL and on subscription the timestamp is set in the data base using the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Now I want to do a select from this table where the subscribe date is between day X and day Y
I tried several queries but somehow they all turn up empty.

Here is my last version

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE subscribe_date BETWEEN '2013-10-07'AND '2013-13-10'
```

As I know for sure this date: 2013-10-08 14:38:49
is in the subscribe_data field It should turn up somehow

What is the best way to do this?

Maybe good to know my 'subscribe_date' column has type 'timestamp' and is auto filled with 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'

Here is the data in this table:

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+
| id | firstname | subscribe_date      |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
| 20 | Peter     | 2013-10-01 14:37:17 |
| 21 | Jack      | 2013-10-08 14:38:49 |
| 22 | Andrew    | 2013-10-10 14:41:03 |
| 23 | Margret   | 2013-10-14 14:42:46 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Try `WHERE DATE(subscribe_date) BETWEEN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) is up to seconds precision usually, you have to add time part:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE (subscribe_date BETWEEN '2013-10-07 00:00:00' AND '2013-12-10 23:59:59')
```

I've fixed your `'2013-13-10'` to `'2013-12-10 23:59:59'` since there's no 13-th month (and in `DATETIME` format it's `YYYY-MM-DD`, so month goes second)

Comment: I tried that but didn't gave any data back to me:
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0008 sec )

Comment: Then obviously you have no records that satisfy your condition

Comment: even if I select a bigger range from 2013-10-01 to 2013-10-14 it doesn't do anything, since there are enough records to meet the condition I think it's the query not that there are no records.

Comment: I just placed some more info in the post, hope that will help as well

Comment: Check if you have some values in your column.

Comment: See the post update with the columns of the table and their contents